# Divide options by border lines, hide when selected

Tags: html, css

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

input + label {
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
  padding-right: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

input:checked + label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="one" name="option" checked/>
<label for="one">One</label>
<input type="radio" id="two" name="option" />
<label for="two">Two</label>
<input type="radio" id="three" name="option" />
<label for="three">Three</label>
```

There are three options, when the option is selected, it should be hidden, including the border line between the option and the next option.

For example,

When I select "One", I should see "Two | Three".

When I select "Two", I should see "One | Three".

When I select "Three", I should see "One | Two".

It does not necessary to be radio buttons, any other possible solutions are also welcome, but I want to achieve this by using CSS only.

Comment: What is it that you want I mean the fiddle provided does what you're looking for. So what is your question?

Comment: This fiddle does not really do what I want, there is a trailing border line

Comment: In that case I don't think you're able to that in CSS only. CSS is not a programming language. You'd have to take a look at JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the CSS selector `:last-of-type`. It's just, using CSS, you ~might~ have to give up that last border line in general.

**code updated below**

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

/*input:first-of-type + label {
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
  padding-right: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}*/

input:not(:first-of-type) + label {
  border-left: solid 1px #000;
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

input:checked + label {
  display: none;
}

/*label:not(:checked):last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}*/
```

```html
<html>
<input type="radio" id="one" name="option" />
<label for="one">One</label>
<input type="radio" id="two" name="option" />
<label for="two">Two</label>
<input type="radio" id="three" name="option" />
<label for="three">Three</label>
<input type="radio" id="four" name="option" checked/>
<label for="four">Four</label>
<input type="radio" id="five" name="option" />
<label for="five">Five</label>

</html>
```

Comment: Can I have "One | Two" when I select "Three"?

Comment: I updated the code. If you really, really want to do it without JS, then you would have to put the border to the left instead of the right. I've keep the old styles in CSS but have commented them out, so that you can see the change. There would be too many limitations with the :not in CSS to accomplish this with the border to the right - that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, a leading border line is there when "One" is selected. I updated the answer to fix this issue.